# Dudas en lectura y escritura FORTRAN

Tags: print, input, fortran, read

Tengo un archivo con millones de datos, este archivo tiene una estructura que inicialmente no se que extensión tiene cada parte... hasta leerlo.
La estructura del texto es a grandes rasgos asi:
-n lineas de información no util (se cuantas lineas son siempre y puedo pasarlas sistematicamente)
-linea caracteristica X
-m lineas de información util (La linea caracteristica me indica cuantos datos son)
-k lineas de informacion basura (no se cuantas son y varian mucho de archivo en archivo).
-linea caracteristica X
-m lineas de información util (La linea caracteristica me indica cuantos datos son)

La primera duda es: Existe alguna formula de buscar una fila que contenga algún dato en particular (linea característica X), asi como el grep en bash? Esto con el objetivo de detectar un pedazo inicial de la información desde donde tengo que leer y así obviar lo que no me interesa y no se cuan largo es.

La segunda duda es: existe alguna forma de imprimir a un output una porción de input de manera textual, sin hacerlo pasar por variables internas del programa y un formato de impresión que tenga que definir yo?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Encontre una solucion para ambos. El juego es leer con un string (CHARACTER (132) ::) lo suficientemente largo el archivo fila por fila.

En el caso de pasar un input a un output directo es:

```
DO I=1,NLINES
  READ(13,'(A132)') READ_WRITE
  WRITE(14,*) TRIM(READ_WRITE)
ENDDO
```

donde se lee desde unit=13 y se imprime en unit=14, haciendo pasar cada fila por el string READ_WRITE. Funciona bien, manteniendo formato y es rapido. Solo hay que determinar el NLINES que se desea imprimir.

En el segundo caso para buscar algo, se puede hacer de manera similar como:

```
DO
  READ(13,'(A132)') READ_WRITE
  IF ((TRIM(READ_WRITE)).EQ.(TRIM(CODIGO))) THEN
    EXIT
  ENDIF
ENDDO
```

Aqui se ocupa un DO infinito, que lee fila por fila, y compara lo leido con CODIGO, un string que contiene lo que se busca. este se puede definir antes desde otras variables. Cuando encuentra la fila deseada, el condicional se activa y cierra el ciclo do. De ahi se puede seguir leyendo tranquilamente.

Saludos